# Intel Xeon stuck at 800mhz CPU Freq on RHEL 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, cpu, intel

Currently running into a headache trying to figure out why my CPU speed is stuck as such a low frequency.  After doing some research, I found that cpuspeedutil does actually control the state of the CPU rather than the BIOS it seems, but every change I try to make using CPUFREQUTIL does not affect the CPU whatsoever.

Currently setup:
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz
RHEL 6.5 with kernel 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Every time I run a command to change the min and max freq settings (CPUSPEEDUTILS), it changes some items as you can see below:

**FYI: The code below is only from A SINGLE CPU CORE (#0 out of 7 Cores)**

As you can see here, I set the Current gov. policy to performance by running:

**cpufreq-set -g performance**

```
[root@f1-w2 /]# cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: **acpi-cpufreq**
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.50 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.50 GHz, 3.50 GHz, 3.30 GHz, 3.10 GHz, 2.90 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: userspace, performance
  current policy: **frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.50 GHz.**
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  **current CPU frequency is 800 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).**
```

It seems that whatever I do to change any of the settings, the above line always reads:
      **current CPU frequency is 800 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).**

You can see below running the cpuinfo shows that the CPU is running @ 3501.000, but when I run ./i7z, it still shows that the frequency is set to 800mhz:

```
    [root@f1-w2 ~]# **cat /proc/cpuinfo**
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz
stepping    : 3
**cpu MHz       : 3501.000** 
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm
bogomips    : 6983.18
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Here is a ls -la of sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root    0 May 23 15:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root    0 May 23 15:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    0 May 23 15:05 cache
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 23 15:13 cpufreq
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    0 May 27 11:02 cpuidle
-r--------  1 root root 4096 May 23 15:05 crash_notes
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 27 11:02 microcode
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 May 27 11:02 node0 -> ../../node/node0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 23 15:10 thermal_throttle
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 23 15:05 topology
```

here is a cat of sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 May 23 15:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root    0 May 23 15:13 ..
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 affected_cpus
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 cpuinfo_cur_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 cpuinfo_max_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 cpuinfo_min_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 cpuinfo_transition_latency
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 related_cpus
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 scaling_available_frequencies
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 23 15:31 scaling_available_governors
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 scaling_cur_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 scaling_driver
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 23 15:39 scaling_governor
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 scaling_max_freq
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 10:28 scaling_min_freq
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 27 11:02 scaling_setspeed
```

As you can see, even when I changed settings VIA CPUFREQ, you can see that the MHZ is still set to 800MHZ:

```
[root@f1-w2 cpufreq]# cat cpuinfo_min_freq
800000
[root@f1-w2 cpufreq]#
```

Immediately changed the MIN CPU FREQ to 2.00ghz and ran cpufreq-info:

```
[root@f1-w2 cpufreq]# cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.50 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.50 GHz, 3.50 GHz, 3.30 GHz, 3.10 GHz, 2.90 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: userspace, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within **2.00 GHz** and 3.50 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  **current CPU frequency is 800 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).**
```

Thought I changed the min freq, it shows between 2.0 and 3.5 ghz, but you can see above that the current CPU FREQ is still 800mhz.

Output from i7z shows it still stuck @ 800mhz:

```
Cpu speed from cpuinfo 3491.00Mhz
cpuinfo might be wrong if cpufreq is enabled. To guess correctly try estimating via tsc
Linux's inbuilt cpu_khz code emulated now
True Frequency (without accounting Turbo) 3491 MHz
  CPU Multiplier 35x || Bus clock frequency (BCLK) 99.74 MHz
Socket [0] - [physical cores=4, logical cores=8, max online cores ever=4]
  TURBO DISABLED on 4 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
  Max Frequency without considering Turbo 3491.00 MHz (99.74 x [35])
  Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  39x/39x/38x/37x
  Real Current Frequency 798.04 MHz [99.74 x 8.00] (Max of below)
        Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %  Temp
        Core 1 [0]:   797.97 (8.00x)         1.4    98.7       1       0    28
        Core 2 [1]:   797.94 (8.00x)           1     100       0       0    28
        Core 3 [2]:   798.04 (8.00x)           1     100       0       0    29
        Core 4 [3]:   797.81 (8.00x)           1      99       1       0    28
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: Currentl BIOS SETTINGS:

[image: BIOS CPU]

[image]

Comment: Currently attempting to update my kernel from 2.6 to 3.14 in hopes that this will solve my issue.  I have tried the 2.6 kernel setup, but to no avail.  Here is the link: http://www.pantz.org/software/cpufreq/usingcpufreqonlinux.html